# How does params come into scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In example code below a new User is created based on the result of calling the method `user_params`. That method uses `params`. How does the `params` variable come into scope? It is not prefixed with the `@` symbol nor does `user_params` take it as an argument.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` is an [instance method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c2494fe88ea7eccf47debb0fbef2b80a3bf92e65/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L656) of class `ActionController:: Metal`.

It [extended by](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L164) class `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: So but then where does `request` in `request.parameters` used in `params` come from? There doesn't seem to be a `request` method?

Comment: @user782220 Of course it's a method, you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a882c69e7b0e5c41b2fea20f0c337107f6203b47/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L128) defined internal attribute, and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a882c69e7b0e5c41b2fea20f0c337107f6203b47/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L192) assigned a value.